# Concatenating a LINQ query and LINQ sort statement

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I'm having a problem joining two LINQ queries.

Currently, my (original) code looks like this

```
s.AnimalTypes.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Type, y.Type));
```

What I'm needing to do is change this based on a date, then select all data past that date, so I have

```
s.AnimalTypes.Select(t=>t.DateChanged > dateIn).ToList()
s.AnimalTypes.Sort((…
```

This doesn't look right as it's not sorting the data selected, rather sorting everything in s.AnimalTypes.

Is there a way to concatenate the two LINQ lines? I've tried

```
s.AnimalTypes.Select(t=>t.DateChanged > dateIn).ToList().Sort((…
```

but this gives me an error on the Sort section.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've looked around and Grouo and OrderBy keep cropping up, but I'm not sure these are what I need here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I believe you want something like:

```
var results = s.AnimalTypes.Where(t => t.DateChanged > dateIn).OrderBy(t => t.Type);
```

You can call `ToList()` to convert to a `List<T>` at the end if required.

There are a couple of fundamental concepts I believe you are missing here -

First, unlike `List<T>.Sort`, the LINQ extension methods *don't change the original collections*, but rather return a new `IEnumerable<T>` with the filtered or sorted results.  This means you always need to assign something to the return value (hence my `var results =` above).

Second, `Select` performs a mapping operation - transforming the data from one form to another.  For example, you could use it to extract out the `DateChanged` (`Select(t => t.DateChanged)`), but this would give you an enumeration of dates, not the original animal types.  In order to filter or restrict the list with a predicate (criteria), you'd use `Where` instead.

Finally, you can use `OrderBy` to reorder the resulting enumerable.

Comment: Thanks - you've explained where I went wrong wonderfully. Code now works as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Select` when you actually want to use `Where`.

`Select` is a projection from one a collection of one type into another type - you won't increase or reduce the number of items in a collection using `Select`, but you can instead *select* each object's name or some other property.

`Where` is what you would use to filter a collection based on a boolean predicate.